# Javascript Regex: replace string with URL if not replaced already

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following problem that I'm trying to solve with String.replace:

I have a random text that contains IDs of tickets in some system e.g. *JIRA-123*. I want to replace then with Markdown links like so:

`text.replace(/(JIRA-\d+)/g, "[$1](example.com?id=$1)");`

The problem I'm struggling with is that I want this operation to be idempotent i.e. if a given ID is already wrapped in the URL I want it to be ignored and I'm struggling to figure out a correct expression to achieve that.

Any help?

Comment: First of all, `generateLink("$1")` is not working.

Comment: Yes, so just follow the second linked thread: use a markdowned URL pattern (p1) and plain URL regex (p2) in an alternation, capture what you need to keep as is, and modify only what is matched and not captured (i.e. `s.replace(/(p1)|p2/g, (x,y) => y ? x : process(x))`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Where does the ticket id `/(JIRA-\d+)/g` expression fit in this solution?

Comment: Okay, I think you meant that p2 a ticket pattern - I think I got it working, thanks :)